# Округление double по школьным правилам

Tags: java

Как добиться правильного "школьного" округления?

```
double lDoubleValue = 2,025;
Double lResult = new BigDecimal(lDoubleValue)
                    .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                    .doubleValue(); //2,02
```

При этом число 2,0251 округляется правильно до 2,03. И число 2,035 => 2,04 что полностью верно. Или использую не тот метод? Но, вроде, он самый-самый школьный.

Answer (score 3):

Добро пожаловать в увлекательный мир двоичного представления действительных чисел в памяти компьютера! Тип данных `double` хранится в памяти согласно стандарту [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Этот стандарт отводит на двоичное представление мантиссы (значащих разрядов) 53 бита. Этого далеко не всегда достаточно, чтобы точно представить конечную десятичную дробь в двоичном виде. Вообще, далеко не каждое действительное число, являющееся конечной дробью в десятичном виде, можно представить конечной дробью в двоичной системе счисления (например, 0.3). Поиграть с представлением десятичных чисел в двоичном виде в формате IEEE 754 можно [здесь](http://www.panojohnson.com/automatons/floating-point-1.xhtml).

Приведённое вами в пример число 2.025 после записи в формате IEEE 754 для 64 разрядов превращается в 2.02499999999999991118215802999. Собственно, это и ломает округление. В документации для `ROUND_HALF_UP` сказано:

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

Округление вверх происходит только если значение округляемого разряда *эквидистантно* (то есть находится на равном расстоянии) от соседей. В вашем же случае это не так, число меньше 0.5e-2, поэтому округляется вниз.

Избежать такого можно, если не использовать `double` или `float` в качестве промежуточного значения, а сразу оперировать с `BigDecimal`, который не подвержен подобным проблемам:

```
Double lResult = new BigDecimal("2.025").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Подскажите, как мне тогда поступить: 1)мне нужно будет суммировать (или умножать int на double), double приходит из БД (поле decimal(18,2)).То есть тут уже без проблем должно быть подставить такое число с двумя знаками в конструктор BigDecimal(Value.doubleValue())? Правильно я понимаю, что в такой ситуации умножение и сложение будут без накопления ошибки работать? И вторая ситуация, я получаю из текстового поля диалога String (еще и с точками как разделитель тысяч) и разбираю этот String на предмет того, Double ли он...но тогда это значение не подходит для округления в BigDecimal,как же быть?

Comment: Если вы число из БД извлекаете как `double`, оно уже будет содержать ошибку, и передача его в конструктор `BigDecimal` её не уберёт. Да, дальнейшие действия, произведённые с `BigDecimal` ошибку не увеличат, но она всё равно останется, так как содержится в исходных данных. Если хотите этого избежать, извлекайте числа из базы в виде строк, и в таком виде передавайте в конструктор `BigDecimal`. Кстати, если в конструктор `BigDecimal` передать строку, не являющуюся числом, он выкинет `NumberFormatException`. Это можно использовть для проверки ввода пользователя.